# VB.net datagridview to chart control devexpress

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, devexpress

I have a study about passing DataGridView values to DevExpress ChartControl. I have X and Y values in my DataGridView (It can have different row count). I would like to use for next loop due to different point counts (needs to stop after last value). Sometimes I have 5 values, sometimes 8, 12, ... etc. I have use code below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        ChartControl1.Series("Series 1").Points.Add(New SeriesPoint(DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value, DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value))
    Next

End Sub
```

See also picture:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the new row in your `DataGridView`. You need to check for new row before adding the values from current row to your chart. To do this you can use the `DataGridView.NewRowIndex` property.
Here is example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If i <> DataGridView1.NewRowIndex Then
            ChartControl1.Series("Series 1").Points.Add(New SeriesPoint(DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value, DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value))
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much nempoBu4, that worked properly now.